# Set tableViewCell-height depended on UIView in this cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, tableview

There is a **tableView** with custom **cell**

There is an **UIView** in this custom cell. UIView has `background` color

Also there is a **label** in **UIView**.

So the task is to set **cell**-height and **UIView**-height depended on `lines count` in this label (label.text, length, etc.). I'm already using

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But it does not allow me to reach result I need. How can I do it?

Comment: did you setup constraints in storyboard?

Comment: yes, I did: all 4 sides of UIView are connected to cell, also label connected to all 4 sides of UIView

Comment: and did you set the label's numberOfLines property to 0?

Comment: I tried. from this way I got bad result: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2015-11-14v19.1447517078.png

Comment: can you show some more of your code or maybe share it via dropbox or something?

Comment: there is no code to share. just 2 lines from 1st post. few screenshots: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2015-11-14v19.1447517984.png, http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2015-11-14v19.1447518079.png ; project is not available to share

Comment: and what about the project itself so that i can check your storyboard setup?

Comment: Is the code in the right place? E.g. If you hardcore a row height to, say, 100, is the code executed correctly?

Comment: there is no problems with code executing. this code is in viewDidLoad